# executeUpdate does not work

Tags: java, jdbc

Hello there I have one question, my executeUpdate statement won't work at all in my project.

It would be great if someone could help me.

Thanks guys.
Here is code:
[code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V2h9k.png)

[output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FEmPn.png)

After highlighted code statement won't update.

Comment: do you get any exceptions?

Comment: No, not a single exception, statement just do not work properly.

Comment: Also it won't throw eception even if I mistake some of the column names.

Comment: are you sure your printing the stacktrace/

Comment: Yes I'm sure about that.

Comment: Did you print out that entire statement and check if query string correct? Maybe some of parameters is null or invalid.

Comment: I printed out query statement and everything is correct, there is no error, it just won't insert row in table.

Comment: Post code as code not as image.

Comment: Hello Aleksandar, please read [how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Regardless of how this plays out you should STOP *injecting* raw user input into *SQL* statements in case [Little Bobby Tables](https://xkcd.com/327/) wound up going to medical school and becoming a doctor.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting AutoCommit to false and commit the transaction.

```
con.setAutoCommit(false);
stmt = con.createStatement();
stmt.executeUpdate(query);
con.commit();
```

Comment: Nah..still don't execute query,in this project that I'm working on, I used executeUpdate at least 20 times,and it works fine,but this 21st time won't work at all..:(

Comment: Did you try inserting data directly into database without program? Was it successful? Post logs of query and program execution.

Comment: Yes i tried that and it was successful this is after filling form and submiting,here is out:

Comment: Info:   Entered else
Info:   com.mysql.jdbc.StatementImpl@5248bee6
Info:   Query: INSERT INTO receiving_paper( pacient_id, department_id, facility_id, disease, ailments,doctor_name, condition ) VALUES( 3, 1, 2, 'arthritis', 'Pain in bones', 'Borska 11b', '///' )

Comment: What is the return value of executeUpdate()? Did it work before(20 times as you mentioned) and broken now?